# How do you calculate the smallest width of an html table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, width, minimum

I have a table that spans most of the page. The width is `calc(100% - 20px)`.

When I drag the window really large, the table adjusts so that it occupies the whole window.

When I shrink the window smaller, it again adjusts so that it occupies the whole window BUT at a certain point it stops adjusting and overflows beyond the edge of the window.

I am wondering how I can calculate that "smallest allowed width" of the table in JS or jQuery, without actually changing the size of my window and then doing a `$('table').width()` or something similar. Worth noting is that this "smallest allowed width" is variable depending on the content of the table. I've search a fair bit and haven't found any good answers.

```
/*table style*/ 
table#myTableId{
    display: table; 
    margin: 10px; 
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 20px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 20px);
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a very small width on the table temporarily and check the live width at that moment using [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

```js
const table = document.getElementById('myTableId');
// get the original width in case it was set
const originalWidth = table.style.width;
// set the table's width to 1px (0 does not work)
table.style.width = '1px';
// get the current width
const smallestWidth = table.getBoundingClientRect().width;
// set the original width back 
table.style.width = originalWidth;

console.log(smallestWidth);
```

```css
table#myTableId {
  display: table;
  margin: 10px;
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 20px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 20px);
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<table id="myTableId">
  <tr>
    <td>Table Cell Content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```